# Swagger JWT Authorization does not work in ASP.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have this in my Startup.cs in the ConfigureServices:

```
services.ConfigureJwt(Configuration);
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Backend.API", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme (Example: 'Bearer 12345abcdef')",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        Array.Empty<string>()
                    }
                });

            });
```

I have this in my Startup.cs in the Configure:

```
 app.UseCors("EnableCors");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

This is my service extension:

```
public static void ConfigureJwt(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var settings = new JwtSettings();
            settings.Key = configuration["JwtSettings:key"];
            settings.Audience = configuration["JwtSettings:audience"];
            settings.Issuer = configuration["JwtSettings:issuer"];
            settings.MinutesToExpiration = Convert.ToInt32(
                    configuration["JwtSettings:minutesToExpiration"]);
            services.AddSingleton(settings);

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
            })
                .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", jwtBearerOptions =>
                {
                    jwtBearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    jwtBearerOptions.SaveToken = true;
                    jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = settings.Issuer,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(settings.Key)),

                        ValidAudience = settings.Audience,

                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(
                                  settings.MinutesToExpiration)
                    };
                });
        }
```

and in my Sagger UI login, this is the reply I get:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "user",
  "firstName": "My FirstName",
  "middleName": "A.",
  "lastName": "My LastName",
  "bearerToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqdWFuIiwianRpIjoiNmQwNjQ4ZWMtOGI4YS00YTBkLTlmYmItZTliYWFmNzdmZjI2IiwiVXNlcklkIjoiMSIsIkZpcnN0TmFtZSI6Imp1YW4iLCJNaWRkbGVOYW1lIjoiQS4iLCJMYXN0TmFtZSI6IkRlbGEgQ3J1eiIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6WyJVc2VyIiwiQWRtaW4iXSwiZXhwIjoxNjA2OTc4MjcyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDM2NiIsImF1ZCI6IkdlbmVyYWxUZW1wbGF0ZSJ9.MMnu-suoae7U3QnXJTa9wI2xDUtdDJTtc63KWyd3bZM",
  "isAuthenticated": true,
  "claims": [
    "User",
    "Admin"
  ]
}
```

Why is it that I still get this error whenever I try to run an endpoint with [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

```
 access-control-allow-origin: * 
 date: Thu03 Dec 2020 06:42:05 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 status: 401 
 www-authenticate: Bearer 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

This is the endpoint I am trying to run:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddCategory(Category model)
        {
            var cm = new CategoryManager(context);
            var result = await cm.Create(model);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created, model);
            }
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, model);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you haven't set RoleClaimType correctly on the authentication scheme? It could be it doesn't know which claim to check for the roles, or it's checking the wrong one.

Comment: Is this issue only on specific endpoints or on all endpoints with Authorization attribute?

Comment: This happens on all endpoints that has Authorize attributes. I don't have any issues when using postman. It's just when I use Swagger.

Comment: Can you try with calling services.ConfigureJwt(Configuration); after services.AddSwaggerGen?

Comment: @EminMesic I tried it. The issue persists Sir.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue because I was just copy and pasting the "bearerToken" value in the Authorize of swagger. What I should do is copy the "bearerToken" value but add "Bearer " at the beginning.